# How do I retrieve data related to a crypto token using numbers as an identifier?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cryptocurrency, coinmarketcap

I've been using Google Sheets to track the value of my various crypto currencies but ran into an issue I'm unable to resolve. The issue is that I have a new crypto currency called 00 (aka L00p) but when I use my regular code to grab the value from CoinMarketCap I get the following error:

> "Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 27
> file: Code.gs"

I believe the issue is that the currency/token identifier is two digits and not letter-based.

My code looks like this:

```
    function getCryptoPrice() {
  var sh2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sh3=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  
  var apiKey=sh2.getRange(1, 2).getValue();
  
  var url="https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=00"
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest',
  qs: {
    start: 1,
    limit: 5000,
    convert: 'USD'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': apiKey
  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true
};
  
  var httpRequest= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  var getContext= httpRequest.getContentText();
  
  var parseData=JSON.parse(getContext);
  sh3.getRange(48, 2).setValue(parseData.data.00.quote.USD.price)

}
```

For comparisons sake, here's the script I used as a template, and which works without issue:

```
function getCryptoPrice() {
  var sh2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sh3=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  
  var apiKey=sh2.getRange(1, 2).getValue();
  
  var url="https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=XCN"
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest',
  qs: {
    start: 1,
    limit: 5000,
    convert: 'USD'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': apiKey
  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true
};
  
  var httpRequest= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  var getContext= httpRequest.getContentText();
  
  var parseData=JSON.parse(getContext);
  sh3.getRange(47, 2).setValue(parseData.data.XCN.quote.USD.price)

}
```

It seems as though the 00 on row 27 in the 00-script appears to be "un-tethered" from the 00 on row 7. And there's no missing end parenthesis, as the error code claims.

Any ideas?

Comment: No guarantee but try this parseData.data["00"].quote.USD.price

Comment: I think that in your script, there are no properties of `uri`, `qs`, `json`, `gzip` in `options` of `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)`. So, I thought that your `requestOptions` is the same with `var requestOptions = {method: 'GET', headers: {'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': apiKey}};`. Please be careful about this. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: @TheWizEd, thank you, but I received an error message due to the bracket. Had tried quotation marks as well, with the same result

Comment: I will tell you I constructed a test object with a similar structure and this worked for me `console.log(data.values["00"].name)` where `data.values = {"00": {name: "hello"}};`

Answer (score 0):

@TheWizEd, thank you!

After changing the code per TheWizEd's suggestion it now works. The thing that tricked me on my first attemt was that I though TheWizEd had forgot to enter a period in after "data", so I added one before testing. That was the wrong thing to do. I also thought that I had to make a similar change on row 7, but that was also not the case.

The complete - and functioning - code looks like this:

```
function getCryptoPrice() {
  var sh2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sh3=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  
  var apiKey=sh2.getRange(1, 2).getValue();
  
  var url="https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=00"
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest',
  qs: {
    start: 1,
    limit: 5000,
    convert: 'USD'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': apiKey
  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true
};
  
  var httpRequest= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  var getContext= httpRequest.getContentText();
  
  var parseData=JSON.parse(getContext);
  sh3.getRange(48, 2).setValue(parseData.data["00"].quote.USD.price)

}
```

Again, huge thank you to TheWizEd!